# Is there an easy way to make a Mac's keyboard functions to be more like Windows

Tags: mac, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I just got a new Mac.

I still use the same old Microsoft keyboard.

The keyboard acts quite different when using Mac.

For example, the copy and paste is done by <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> instead of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

Also switching between opened windows is done by <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> instead of <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Is there an easy way to set the flavour of my Mac’s keyboard to be more like Windows?

I know I can manually set every shortcut - but I'm looking for a solution which will help me do it with single or few actions...

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure that this is doable and likely not even advisable.

Messing around with system-wide functions may end up breaking just about every app on your Mac. If I may illustrate.

So lets say that you have made changes to macOS that do exactly what you want. Now you go to your dock and open up your favorite text editor and start typing. Then you realize that you need a snippet out of a Safari window you just covered up by launching your editor. so you tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch apps but instead of the expected App Switcher coming up your editor brings up a FIND dialog (or whatever...)

You see **EVERY** Mac application expects <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to bring up the app switcher. It is a reserved keyboard shortcut in macOS. Reserved for macOS and macOS **only.** Same for copy/paste.

Yes individual developers can modify how their app responds to reserved macOS commands (I'm looking at you Adobe Photoshop and your insistence on using <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for something that *isn't* "hide frontmost app.")

But assuming you can find a way to do this with a keyboard macro program like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/). **Should you?** Well it's your Mac so you can if you want to. But *I* wouldn't do it.

And I support both Macs and Windows PCs and go back and forth all day long. It's something you get used to. Muscle memory is a pain to overcome but probably better for the long term stability and utility of your Mac to just buckle down and get used to the differences.